# Computational hard math problem

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Given a square filled randomly with the numbers $1$ to $N$, for instance
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
16 &12 & 9 & 1\\
11 & 3 & 4 & 7\\
 2&  8 & 5&14\\
 6& 10& 15& 13 \end{array}$$

The task is to group these numbers into $N/2$ sets ($8$ in this case), with the following rules:

- a set can contain as many numbers as you want
- only adjacent numbers can be in the same set

Example: $8+5+14+7$ and $16$ on its own, would be allowed, but not $2+3$ or $2+4$.

Once the $N/2$ sets are formed, the score is the lowest sum of the numbers found in any of the sets formed.
Example: the grouping $16+11$, $12+3$, $9+4$, $ 1+7$, $2+6$, etc would have a score of $8$.

Question: Find a strategy that finds the highest score.

Brute force works for this $4\times 4 $ square, but in practice we have more like $10\times 10$ squares or larger.

Some background: The problem is a stylized version of a problem that came up in the company I work for, concerning assigning workloads to collaborators. We use an algorithm that looks the lowest pairs of sets and tries to add to them.

Example: $3+4$ is the lowest pair, so this is the first set, followed by $1+7$, $2+6$, $8+5$, $9+(3+4)$, etc.

Comment: Some questions: Can there be repited numbers in the square? If $N$ is not even, what's the meaning of $N/2$?

Comment: As, I said, the problem is stylized from the real life problem. In reality the numbers are the number of clients with problems in regions assigned to our collaborators. So let's assume that N is even and that the numbers are subsequent 1 to N.